# flutter timeofday calculations

Tags: flutter, addition, calculation, timeofday

in my flutter app the user picks a time and I need to simply add some hours and minute to it to display the result. Is that easily possible? Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a function like TimeOfDay.add().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Use Date Time for that: You can add Minutes or Hours as you like.

```
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2))); // result is 2hrs ahead of current time
```