# How to set the default dateTime 2 hours ahead of the current time?

Tags: flutter

Whenever I open the page which has my DateTime function on it, the default time that it shows is the current time, which then I have to change. How do I change it so that the default time is 2 hours ahead of the current time? This is not a timezone issue, I have looked at that.

```
DateTime _time = DateTime.now();

_selectTime() async {
    DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
      context,
      showTitleActions: true,
      onConfirm: (dateTime) {
        if (dateTime != null) {
          _time = dateTime;
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I would like the default time to be 2 hours ahead of the current time. So the current time is 07:30, I would like it to rather be 09:30.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flutter timeofday calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015124/flutter-timeofday-calculations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DateTime _time = DateTime.now();

_selectTime() async {
    _time = _time.add(new Duration(hours: 2));
    DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
      context,
      showTitleActions: true,
      onConfirm: (dateTime) {
        if (dateTime != null) {
          _time = dateTime;
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just put it in the _selectTime function

Comment: This has fixed my display, but now my DateTime picker is still on the original time. eg: display is 09:30 but the DateTime picker still says 07:30

Comment: You have to set the new date to the variable